# word add-in written in angular - find and select text

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js

I am in charge of a word add-in and need to add new features, but I'm failing hard and hopefully anyone can help me :)

I have a button and if this button is clicked the first occurence of a given string should be selected in the word text.

Thank you!

package.json
    "@types/office-js": "0.0.75",

edit:

HTML Code

```
<a href="#" class="button-select-text (click)="selectText(givenString)">
```

Angular Code

```
public selectText(givenString: string) {
    console.log('String to select: ' + givenString);
    if (this._common.officeVersion[0] !== '16') {
        this._common.getWordFile('', Office.FileType.Text)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Text from Word: ' + response.fileContent);
                // todo now select/mark the givenString in word itself
            });

    } else {
        Word.run(context => {
            const wordText = context.load(context.document.body, 'text');
            console.log('Text from Word: ' + wordText);
            // todo now select/mark the givenString in word itself
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your problem, can you show any code? Or generate a stackblitz link?

Comment: i added codesnippets, but my problem is that I do not know how to select/mark text in word from the add-in

Comment: I can't help you with that information, if you can upload in stackblitz a version to test and "play" with it maybe I should help you because I have never used office-js. By the way, I hope you will find help! Regards

Comment: I recommend you start with **Script Lab** - a free Add-in that runs in the Word application interface. That provides numerous samples in TypeScript, including one that demonstrates how to *search* a term.

Comment: @Cindy Meister
Thank you, I will look into the samples of Script Lab!

Answer (score 1):

In the `Word.run`, you can use the [Word.Range.select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.range?#select-selectionmode-) method to select the string in Word.

I can't find a way to programmatically select data with the Shared APIs (that you are using in the pre-2016 branch of your code).

Comment: So selecting a sting is only possible in Word 2016+?

Comment: @ColdFridge As far as I can discover, it is only possible in Word 2016+